# Select rows where total elapsed value is less than or equal to

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

`id  |  name  |  elapsed`
`1     James       0`
`2     John       60`
`3     Kerry      60`
`4     Janet      60`
`5     Katie      60`

Based on the results above , how can I select names where the 'elapsed' value total is less than or equal to 120? For those results, that would involve selecting the names 'James', 'John' and 'Kerry'. If I changed the total elapsed to 180 it would also select 'Janet'.

How can I construct a query that returns this?

Comment: So you want a running total, correct?  Pull all lines in the order of the id and when the elapsed running total reaches the cap of 120 you want it to stop? I'm just clarifying, but if that's what you want it's over my head. :)

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: @Zack That is correct, thanks Zack :)

Comment: @Strawberry What use is it me showing you what didn't work? Do you just want to know that I tried? If so, I tried and I failed.

Comment: SO likes to see effort.

Comment: @Strawberry I get that, well I've spent the past 30 mins trying if it means anything, and my attempts were all similar to Pants' original answer. But now I know it's called a running total I am searching around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.name, 
    t1.elapsed
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN your_table t2 ON (t1.id >= t2.id)
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.elapsed
HAVING SUM(t2.elapsed) <= 120
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to think about...

```
 SELECT * FROM ints;
 +---+
 | i |
 +---+
 | 0 |
 | 1 |
 | 2 |
 | 3 |
 | 4 |
 | 5 |
 | 6 |
 | 7 |
 | 8 |
 | 9 |
 +---+

 SELECT i,@x:=@x+i running FROM ints i,(SELECT @x:=0)var ORDER BY i;
 +---+----------+
 | i | running  |
 +---+----------+
 | 0 |        0 |
 | 1 |        1 |
 | 2 |        3 |
 | 3 |        6 |
 | 4 |       10 |
 | 5 |       15 |
 | 6 |       21 |
 | 7 |       28 |
 | 8 |       36 |
 | 9 |       45 |
 +---+----------+
```

Comment: I like your style of teaching to fish, but don't you think this is a bit too hard?

Comment: No - I don't think so - but I may be mistaken!

Comment: You are indeed mistaken. My fish brain sees this, tries to relate it to the question and then my brain times out

Comment: Well, you can see that there's a running total going on here, right?

Comment: @jskidd3 What about you calculate the running total of the elapsed column first. Without anything else.

Comment: @Strawberry I suggest you change either `i` or `@i` to a different variable name to make it a little bit easier to understand.

Comment: @Strawberry I can see a running total, but I have hard results, not data that looks like it's generated by some form of loop. I haven't had to touch variables in MySQL before now so it does look a little complicated!

Comment: All this variable stuff does is take the value in the preceeding row and add it to the value in the next row - voila, a running total.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT '1' AS ID, 'James' AS Name, 0 AS Elapsed
    UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'John', 60
    UNION ALL SELECT '3', 'Kerry', 60
    UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'Janet', 60
    UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'Katie', 60
) AS X
WHERE 1=1
    AND (
        SELECT SUM(Elapsed)
        FROM (
            SELECT '1' AS ID, 'James' AS Name, 0 AS Elapsed
            UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'John', 60
            UNION ALL SELECT '3', 'Kerry', 60
            UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'Janet', 60
            UNION ALL SELECT '5', 'Katie', 60
        ) AS Y
        WHERE Y.ID <= X.ID
    ) <= 180
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Apologies - I have an aversion to correlated subqueries, but this seems fine.